# Add an array of integers as a whole number in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, math

I have to write a program that stores a whole number one digit as a time in an array. For example 1234 is a[0] 1, a[1] 2, a[2] 3, a[3] 4. The numbers will be originally stored as char so I need to convert them into type int. The goal is to take 2 positive integers that are 20 or fewer digits in length and output the sum of the numbers.

I must use the paper-and-pencil addition algorithm. The solution must be stored in an array of size 20 and then written on screen. If the output is bigger than an array of size 20 then no output should be given and the screen should display "Integer Overflow."

So far I have this coding completed:

```
int max;
int max_1;
char number_1[100];
int a;
int max_2;
char number_2[100];
int b;


printf( "\nEnter the total number of digits you wish to display:\n");
scanf_s( "%d", &max);

printf("\nEnter the size of the first integer you wish to add:\n");
scanf("%d", &max_1);
printf("\nEnter the first integer one number at a time seperated by spaces:\n");
while (a = 0, a < max_1, ++a)
{
    scanf_s("%c", number_1[a]);
}

printf("\nEnter the size of the second integer you wish to add:\n");
scanf("%d", &max_2);
printf("\nEnter the second integer one number at a time seperated by spaces:\n");
while (b = 0, b < max_2, ++b)
{
    scanf_s("%c", number_2[b]);
}
    return 0;
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to convert the numbers that are input into actual integer form since they are all stored separately in the array. Also I am unsure how I would go about converting the integer back into an array of size 20 and how I would figure out if the output would be of size 20 or greater.

I apologize for my long question. I am new to coding and am not overly good with reasoning things out. I am sure there is a simple solution for this however I cannot think of it. Any comments, solutions or suggestions would help.

Comment: Two problems: You're not using `scanf` correctly, it needs a *pointer* to where to store what it reads. And second, you don't use `scanf` correctly, as `"%c"` will read *all* input, including spaces and newlines (and newlines there will be if you end each input with a press of the `Enter` key).

Comment: Oh and you don't use your loops correctly either. You seem to be wanting the `for` loop, but it's not quite correct for that either. All in all it seems you're kind of guessing about the syntax and usage of the language, which is never a good way to learn. Either get a book, *any* book really, or take a few classes.

Comment: Lastly, about that reading of character, if you want numbers why don't *read* numbers? Using e.g. `"%1d"` and read into an `int` will solve your problem of conversion, as well as solve one of the problem of your `scanf` usage (since that format will skip leading white-space).

Comment: Note that an array of chars can be read at once using the format `"%s"`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think you would want to avoid reading as numbers (although that would be great) anything with more than about 10 digits is going to overflow and hes going for 20...

Comment: @samuelnj Reading the numbers digit by digit into an array (of `int` values) should not be a problem.

Comment: what if the char size is more than integer's max limit? How should the program behave in that case?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude makes sense, thought you were suggesting readying the entire thing

Comment: @someprogrammerdude Do you have an example of the coding you are talking about? As I said I am fairly new to coding. I am currently taking a course online and have the course book however I cannot find any examples of this type of question in the book. I appreciate all of your comments and I will try to fix the mistakes you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example showing how to read the digits, one by one, directly as integers:

```
int max_1;
printf("\nEnter the size of the first integer you wish to add:\n");
scanf("%d", &max_1);

int number_1[max_1];  // Use variable-length array

printf("\nEnter the first integer one number at a time seperated by spaces:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < max_1; ++i)
{
    scanf_s("%1d", &number_1[i]);
}
```

After this, each element in the array `number_1` is a single-digit `int` value. Most significant digit at index `0`, least significant digit at index `max_1 - 1`.

Comment: So after I implement the coding you just posted I have find a way to change the array elements into one big integer. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this as well as how to add them. Sorry for all of the questions but I have been working on this code for a few days and can't seem to advance with my coding.

Comment: @ayetman96 Does your pen-and-paper algorithm require it to be one big number? Or does it work on the single digits? If it's for single digits, why not *keep* it as single digits? Otherwise you have to use a *bignum library* for the numbers, and then as a separate step separate out the digits once again (since no addition algorithm works on whole numbers).

Comment: The question proposed by my professor says convert the individual array elements to a single integer to be added with the other single integer. I am unsure how I perform this step as well as the addition. I have tried simple "1+1" but this doesn't work for this since they are stored in an array.

Comment: @ayetman96 If you want to be able to handle 20-digit (or larger) numbers then there is no standard type that can do that.